# How to create F# azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Trying to create azure function in F# in the azure portal.
Selected .net as a runtime in function app settings, and now when I create new function C# one got created by default and there is no way to select or change language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Functions 2.x doesn't currently support .fsx scripts because of issues with F# Interactive and .NET Core, which means you can't add F# functions via the portal. It does support compiled F# though, so you can still use F# via Visual Studio, VS Code or the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

"Starting with version 2.x of the Azure Functions runtime, all functions in a function app must be authored in the same language."
Quote from MS Azure function documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference

If possible delete function app and recreate then you can have options for f#

Comment: Tried that, still same result - no language selection even on empty just created functional app.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create an F# function, all you have to do is manually delete the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME App Setting from your app, and refresh the portal.

once you do this you can go to runtime v1 and select the language of your choice

the portal should look like this once you perform the above steps.

[image]